# Azure Synapse Attempting to Change data type from varchar to BIGINT

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse

When I execute the following on Azure Synapse Serverless SQL I get the following error:

**Error converting data type varchar to bigint.**

The code is as follows:

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
 (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ts_primarysecondaryfocus)RowNum FROM [dbo].[account]
 ),CTE2 AS
 (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ts_primarysecondaryfocus)RowNum FROM [dbo].[OptionsetMetadata]
 )
 SELECT C1.Id,C1.SinkCreatedOn,C1.SinkModifiedOn,C1.statecode,C1.statuscode
       ,CASE WHEN C1.ts_primarysecondaryfocus<>ISNULL(C2.ts_primarysecondaryfocus,'')THEN C2.ts_primarysecondaryfocus ELSE C1.ts_primarysecondaryfocus END AS ts_primarysecondaryfocus
       ,C1.customertypecode,C1.address1_addresstypecode,C1.accountclassificationcode,C1.ts_easeofworking 
       ,CASE WHEN C1.ts_ukrow<>ISNULL(C2.ts_ukrow,'')THEN C2.ts_ukrow ELSE C1.ts_ukrow END AS ts_ukrow 
       ,C1.preferredappointmenttimecode,C1.xpd_relationshipstatus,C1.ts_relationship
 FROM CTE1 C1 LEFT JOIN CTE2 C2 ON C1.RowNum = C2.RowNum
```

The problem is I don't why Azure Synapse is trying to convert the datatype to BIGINT.

Also, I'm not sure how to manually change the data type to BIGINT

I just thought I would update this question, because I have just noticed that the field ts_primarysecondaryfocus is BIGINT, in the table but VARCHAR in the view, see image. Therefore, I think I need help changing the data type in either the table or view.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey @Patterson, can you please edit the question to include more details about the error (to which line the error is pointing)?

Comment: Hi Saideep, thanks for getting in touch. The full error is ```Failed to execute query. Error: Error converting data type varchar to bigint. Statement ID: {7F9AD0EB-2368-4323-8BBC-AF953DDEE030} | Query hash: 0xE961B2E4AE046D3C | Distributed request ID: {09C0407C-A034-438F-ABF2-8BFD4867B82C}. Total size of data scanned is 3 megabytes, total size of data moved is 1 megabytes, total size of data written is 0 megabytes.```

Comment: So, `C1.ts_primarysecondaryfocus<>ISNULL(C2.ts_primarysecondaryfocus,'')` and `C1.ts_ukrow<>ISNULL(C2.ts_ukrow,'')`... are any of those columns using the `bigint` data type?

Comment: Hi AlwaysLearning, yes both are using bigint data types

Comment: Hi Always, I think you might be on to something ... I have updated the question. It will be interesting to hear your thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing values of 2 different data types in the `case` statement of ts_primarysecondaryfocus.

Convert one of the column data types to match the other in the expression to avoid the error.

Example query:

[image]

In your code, change the case statement of ts_primarysecondaryfocus to include the datatype conversion using convert.

```
CASE WHEN convert(varchar,C1.ts_primarysecondaryfocus)<>ISNULL(C2.ts_primarysecondaryfocus,'')THEN C2.ts_primarysecondaryfocus ELSE convert(varchar,C1.ts_primarysecondaryfocus) END AS ts_primarysecondaryfocus
```